# Consume Data From this endpoint

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, api, jsonserializer

I am getting tdata from a certain endpoint and the problem id on serialization to my classes. I want to cast the bellow data to my class but cant get how the class should be structured. Check out the data .....

```
  {
    "-LYG_AI_oGYjNBrzMlKF": {
    "chatDispayText": "",
    "chatId": "-LYG_AI_oGYjNBrzMlKF",
    "chatName": "",
    "chattype": "single",
    "imageUrl": "https://wallpaper.wiki/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/wallpaper.wiki-Amazing-celebrities-hd-wallpaper-PIC-WPD004734.jpg",
    "lastMessageSent": "aiye",
    "lastMessageSentTime": 1549704416263,
    "synched": false,
    "users": {
    "-LYG_AIZ5MvTbjR7DACe": "Uicpm3L15TX0c15pKCI6KUEARyB3",
    "-LYG_AI_oGYjNBrzMlKE": "Xsr0z9lsqNOEytX61lJvaGz1A8F2"
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? What went wrong?

Comment: if your problem in define class structures, use the online tools for json to class like http://json2csharp.com/.

Comment: i actually harked the first one with 
            var datas = (JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, tempAppChat>>(chats));

 but this update proves challenging

Answer (score 1):

If the data you get out the endpoint has a dynamic structure, you can make use of a key-vale pair collection or a dictionary. For instance:

```
JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(Data); // This would already give you a key-value pair collection
Dictionary<String,Object> collection = new Dictionary<String, Object>();
foreach(var obj in jObject){
    collection.Add(obj.Key, obj.Value);
}
```

However, this isn't a strongly typed approach which means that it is not effective in the majority of scenarios. A better solution when dealing with endpoints would be to define a class with fixed schema, actually something you need in your code, and then map the class to the object yielded by the endpoint using a metadata struct. For example:

```
public class ChatInfoModel
{
    [JsonProperty(Metadata.ChatId)]
    public long ChatId { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(Metadata.ChatId, Required = Required.AllowNull)]
    public String Message { get; set; }
}
public struct Metadata
{
    public const String ChatId = "userChatId"; 
    public const String Message = "messageTxt";
}
```

And then

```
var deserializedObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ChatInfoModel>(data);
```

However, if your class has the exact same naming convention (but should not necessarily follow the camelCase naming convention) for its properties as in the serialized data, the `JsonProperty` attribute would not be needed.

You can also deserialize the object without using `JsonProperty` attribute manually using the first approach, and it is actually advantageous in certain scenarios where your schema comes from a configuration file rather than a struct.

Answer (score 0):

Take inspiration from the Structure below:

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public LYG_AI_Ogyjnbrzmlkf LYG_AI_oGYjNBrzMlKF { get; set; }
}

public class LYG_AI_Ogyjnbrzmlkf
{
    public string chatDispayText { get; set; }
    public string chatId { get; set; }
    public string chatName { get; set; }
    public string chattype { get; set; }
    public string imageUrl { get; set; }
    public string lastMessageSent { get; set; }
    public long lastMessageSentTime { get; set; }
    public bool synched { get; set; }
    public Users users { get; set; }
}

public class Users
{
    public string LYG_AIZ5MvTbjR7DACe { get; set; }
    public string LYG_AI_oGYjNBrzMlKE { get; set; }
}
```